# Setting an attribute to a certain value automatically to every element that gets added to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a document that is dynamically manipulated with lightbox-like divs being added to and removed from the DOM all the time based on user interactions. Some of these divs contain hyperlinks, and I would like to ensure that whenever any of these anchor elements are clicked, the linked document displays in an iframe, and not the root browsing context. In other words, I need to ensure that all anchor elements added to the DOM have their `target` attribute set to, say, the value `"foo"`, as soon as the anchor elements are introduced into the DOM.

One idea that occurred to me was to work with the `HTMLAnchorElement` prototype, so that any and all prototypal descendants of it would inherit the value of its `target` property, but I can't quite make that work.

Comment: There is a *document.links* collection that is every link in the document. Might be useful? Do not mess with host object prototypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a click handler to the document to intercept the link clicks?

```
$(document).on('click', '.lightbox a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(e.target).attr('href');
    // now open url in iframe
});
```

I'm foolishly assuming you're using jQuery already. If you're not, you can translate it :)

Comment: Question is tagged as Javascript. This is jQuery.

Comment: @fubbe jQuery is a very popular javascript library. How is this not javascript?

Comment: Iam aware of that. But the question is still tagged for a javascript solution. That's actually how the forum works.

Comment: That's why I didn't say "You must use jQuery for this." I offered a jQuery solution in the event the OP was using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably modify your links "target" attribute, instead of attaching the event handler (that could be a possible solution too)

For example, one possible solution could be:

HTML

```
<iframe name="myIframe" src="" />
```

Javascript

```
var containers, links;
containers = document.getElementsByClassName("lightbox-class"); //or whatever class lightbox have.

for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    links = containers[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var x = 0; x < links.length; x++) {
        links[x].target = "myIframe";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult. Elements can be created in multiple ways, some very difficult to hijack.

However, since you only need it at click events, you can add an event listener to `window` for the capture phase. This will ensure you detect the event before some other element stops its propagation.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') // It's an <a> element
    e.target.target = 'iframe'; // Add `target` attribute
}, true); // Capture phase
```

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a')
    e.target.target = 'iframe';
}, true);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://wikipedia.org">Load Wikipedia</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://duckduckgo.com">Load DuckDuckGo</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Load Example</a></li>
</ul>
<iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: How well supported Is the capture phase?

Comment: @RobG The first definition of `addEventListener` (DOM2) already included capture, so there shouldn't be much problems. But IE didn't support `addEventListener` before version 9.